# Older iTunes Installs on Latests OS X’s

Tags: itunes

Is there a program where I can have 2 iTunes installed on the OS X or can I uninstall the iTunes 12+ in a High Sierra and re-install an iTunes 9 or 10 instead? I don’t care about any iPhone or iPod syncing, I just want to use the old iTunes interface.

Answer (score 1):

As iTunes is an Apple-written application and has many low and system-level hooks and API calls, it would be difficult to maintain more than one installed  version.

iTunes 12 is probably the oldest version you could install on High Sierra.

If you really prefer the older version(s), consider creating a Mac OS X virtual machine and playing your media from inside that.

You might also wish to consider an alternative media player, such as [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/), [Vox](https://apps.apple.com/ke/app/vox-mp3-flac-music-player/id461369673?mt=12&app=apps&ign-mpt=uo%3D4), or [Amarok](https://community.kde.org/Amarok).

Answer (score 1):

The program [Retroactive](https://github.com/cormiertyshawn895/Retroactive) is able to install iTunes (and other programs) on non-compatible Macs, namely Catalina, Big Sur, and Monterey.

I do not believe that it would meet your use case, as you are trying to install an older iTunes on a computer that already has iTunes

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does work to install earlier versions. I experimented yesterday using AppZapper to dump iTunes versions and reinstall many earlier versions over-and-over again and they all work in any OS X version, I think?... or I tried it in Mountain Lion, Yosemite and High Sierra and it worked in all 3 OS X's. I hate the interface of iTunes 11 and 12's.

Any iTunes version after 10.3.1 you will get a nuisance error message popup in the beginning during program startup that says a missing component (-42401) needs to be installed and to update, but if you just ignore it's gone until the next startup. You will loose any syncing of devices ofcourse.

My aim here is to make Snow Leopard my main workstation with all of my music files in iTunes 10.0 and then install Capitan or any Sierra into the VM and use that updated iTunes to sync to my iPhone 12. But I don't think there is a VM that can be installed ontop of Snow Leopard unless you do know?